# Validacion de datos en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Controller

```
    public function update($id){
     $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    if($method != 'PUT' || $this->uri->segment(3) == '' || is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3)) == FALSE){
        json_output(400,array('status' => 400,'message' => 'Bad request.'));
    } else {
        $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
        if($params['name'] == "" || $params['lastname'] == "" || $params['password'] == "" || $params['mobile'] == ""){
            $respStatus = 400;
            $response = array('status' => 400,'message' => 'Hay datos que no deben ser vacios','data'=> $params);
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Usermodel');
            $response = $this->Usermodel->edit($id,$params);
        }
        json_output($respStatus,$response);

    }
}
```

> Model

```
public function edit($id,$data){
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('usuario',$data);
        if($this->db->trans_status() == FALSE){
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return array('status' => 500,'message' => 'Internal server error.');
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Datos actualizados');
        }

    }
```

mi problema es que siempre me manda a error 400 "Hay datos que no deben ser vacíos", estoy mandando con postman para las pruebas. no se si la validación la estoy haciendo correctamente, como pueden ver en el controlador imprimo por json $params el cual me arroja `null`

Comment: como estas enviando los datos al metodo update()?

Comment: puede usted consulta en el siguiente link donde me muestra como validad en el controlador o consulte la parte de va https://www.uno-de-piera.com/hacer-un-insert-con-el-framework-codeigniter/   o consulta la funcion https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial

Comment: El Problema que te de error 404 son tus rutas si las estas haciendo mal o no le especificas que le vas a pasar un parametro entonces no encontrara la pagina y te enviara ese error. Hay que Revisarlas.

Comment: envio los datos por PUT